# Submodules of a Noetherian module are finite intersections of irreducible submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> If $M$ is a Noetherian $R$-module then every submodule of $M$ is a finite intersection of irreducible submodules.

Please show me the way how to get the proof of this statement.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27018/proper-submodules-of-noetherian-modules-are-intersections-of-indecomposable-modu